# Angular2 Routing for child level

Tags: angular

My App.ts file contains code:

`{ path: '/Issuebook/...', component:Issuebook, as:'Issuebook' },`

The routeConfig and the HTML contains

```
<li><a [router-link]="['/Issuebook','Duebook']">Issuebook</a></li>
```

and in the child component i have written code for routing like:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/DueBookChildComponent', component: Duebook, as: 'Duebook'}
])
```

and HTML for child is:

```
<a [router-link]="['./Duebook']"><button class="btn btn-warning">Due Book</button></a>
```

My problem is when i open `Issuebook` route it will open with its child route too but i want to open only `Issuebook` and child rout only when i click on the `Due Book` button.

I have watched this video for reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1NB-HG0ZH4 .

but i cant understand properly the use of path: `'/Issuebook/...'` (this ...) in the child routing. Has anyone got a working example of child routing?

Comment: Do you have a gist or plunker for this code?

Comment: Note that there's a breaking change incoming, so you can in a future release (or now if you clone the repo and build it yourself) the new `useAsDefault` property, see this PR [#5352](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/5352)

Comment: @skusunam no i haven't any plnkr or gist for this code. because code is too lengthy.

Comment: @EricMartinez will you please provide the any plunker for the usage of useAsDefault.

Comment: @Pardeepjain here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EHH7beg9azZiegtXQ7ib?p=preview), it took me a while, it is still not merged on the main repo, so I had to pull it down from `@btford's` repo